# grabbing a substring of an SQL field where a string matches part of the field

Tags: mysql

Hi all and thank you for reading...

Ive been trying to find a fix to a SQL and PHP problem I have. below is a snippet of the table I am trying to work with.

The table is called web_navbar_links the field is called slug

```
+------------------+-------+
|       slug       | child |
+------------------+-------+
|business-multiseat|   1   |
+------------------+-------+
|consumer-multiseat|   1   |
+------------------+-------+
```

I have a string "multiseat" I need an SQL query that will search all the rows and pull back the first substring "business" and/or "consumer" that match the string "multiseat" and are also child='1'.

I have tried concat_ws and LIKE but dont feel they are the correct commands unless ofc I dont understand there usage :D

If anyone can help me I would be very greatful.

Dan.

Comment: So you don't want "business-multiseat" returned, you want "business"? Will the '-multiseat' always appear after the business, i.e. you're only ever searching for a suffix?

Comment: Yes i will only ever need the suffix before the delimiter returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT SUBSTRING(slug, 1, INSTR(slug, '-') - 1) result
FROM     web_navbar_links
WHERE    SUBSTRING(slug FROM INSTR(slug, '-') + 1) = 'multiseat' AND child = 1;
```

Note however that this could be slow if you plan to have many rows in your `web_navbar_links` table. Such a query will not be able to use an index on `slug` if one exists.

---

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE web_navbar_links (id int, slug varchar(70), child int);

INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (1, 'business-multiseat', 1);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (2, 'business-singleseat', 1);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (3, 'consumer-noseat', 1);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (4, 'consumer-multiseat', 1);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (5, 'something', 1);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (6, 'business-multiseat', 2);
INSERT INTO web_navbar_links VALUES (7, 'something-else', 2);
```

Result:

```
SELECT   id, SUBSTRING(slug, 1, INSTR(slug, '-') - 1) result
FROM     web_navbar_links
WHERE    SUBSTRING(slug FROM INSTR(slug, '-') + 1) = 'multiseat' AND child = 1;

+------+----------+
| id   | result   |
+------+----------+
|    1 | business |
|    4 | consumer |
+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think I understand the gist of this script, am I correct in asuming that the shortenned version of slug will be returned as $row->slug from the db?

Comment: @Daniel: No, as `$row->result`, unless you change the `result` alias in the first line of the query :)